# Make org mode use helm-find files when inserting local file links

Tags: org-mode, helm

How can I achieve that org mode uses `helm-find-files` if I insert a link to a local file via `C-u C-c C-l`?

Comment: Org mode uses `read-file-name` for this and, according to its doc string,  that uses a variable `read-file-name-function`. You might be able to find a `helm` function that you can assign to that variable, but you should read the doc string of `read-file-name-function` before you go looking.

Comment: When you press `C-u C-c C-l`, do you not see a helm buffer? You probably need to turn helm-mode on. You can also use `helm-find-files` directly. Select the file and press `C-c @`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable helm-mode, for example: `(helm-mode 1)`.

Another option is to call `helm-find-files` followed by `C-c @` to insert the link.